# ggplot2 pie and donut on same plot with only summary data

Tags: r, ggplot2, pie-chart

I'm trying to produce something similar to this chart from the moonBook package as shown [here](https://rpubs.com/cardiomoon/398623)

[image]

My data regards participation in telework programs for several dozen organizations, and all I have are gross percentages, not individual responses.

So for Organization X, I know:

```
Telework rate: 33%
No telework rate: 67%
```

For those who do telework, their frequencies are:

```
Very infrequently: 19.8%
1-2 days/month: 4.8%
1-2 days/week: 7.9%
3-4 days/week: 0.4%
Every work day: 0.1%
```

For those who do not telework, their reasons are:

```
Must be physically present: 11.5%
Technical limitations: 7.1%
Not authorized: 25.5%
Choose not to: 23.9%
```

I'd like the central pie to show the telework/no-telework breakout for a given organization and the outer donut to show the frequency/reason.  But I'm at a loss as to how to proceed as virtually every example I've found begins from individual responses.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution that might be really close to what you are looking for.

I used some data similar to what you showed:

```
df<-data.frame(Org=c("Tele",rep(c("Tele","NotTele"),each=4)),
                     CatFreq = LETTERS[1:9],
               Freq = c(19.8,4.8,7.9,0.4,0.1,11.5,7.1,25.5,22.9))
```

The rest of the code

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  #Calculate cumulative sums
  mutate(cumsum = cumsum(Freq),
         min = cumsum-Freq) %>%
  #Calculate cumulative sums by Org
  group_by(Org) %>%
  mutate(cumsum2 = max(cumsum(Freq))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  #Get mid point to print labels for Org levels
  mutate(mid = ifelse(Org == "Tele", cumsum2 / 2, min(cumsum2) + (max(cumsum2)/2) ) ) %>%
  #Do the ggplot by doing two geom_rect, 1 for Org, 1 for CatFreq
  ggplot()+
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = 1,
                xmax = 2,
                ymin = min, 
                ymax = cumsum,
                fill = Org))+
  #Add labels for Org
  geom_text(aes(x = 1 + ((2 - 1)/2), 
                y = mid,
                label = paste(Org, paste0(cumsum2, "%"), sep= "\n"))) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = 2,
                xmax = 3,
                ymin = min, 
                ymax = cumsum,
                fill = CatFreq))+
  #Add labels for CatFreq
  geom_text(aes(x = 2 + ((3 - 2)/2), 
                y = min + ((cumsum - min)/2),
                label = paste(CatFreq, paste0(Freq, " %"), sep= "\n"))) +
  #Changing the plot to pie
  coord_polar("y", start = 0) +
  #Making it a doughnut
  xlim(c(0,4)) + 
  #Set theme void
  theme_void() +
  #Eliminate legend
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

Comment: I've actually managed to manipulate the data to work with the moonBook package functions (bit more brute force than I'd like, but oh well) but now face a new problem...labels for very small donuts overlap.  I tried adding geom_text_repel but that destroys the inner pie.  Guess this is a new question at this point...

Comment: Yes, that is a problem. Maybe you could eliminate the `geom_text` in the figure and just show the labels and its percentage in the legend. That might be easier to read.